# Why is Opera browser cropping some of the pictures?

Tags: css, opera, padding, margin, image

Right now, the portfolio section of my website has the top three images showing properly.  But in the Opera browser, it "crops" the top and bottom of the rest of the images, leaving only the very middle of each of the images to show.  All of the other browsers show every picture in the portfolio section properly.  I've tried messing with the margin and padding on the pictures with no luck.  If anyone can help me figure out what is going on, I would surely appreciate it!  =]  Click [here](http://abrielshipley.com) to get to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#portfolio {
    overflow: auto;
    display: block !important; /* aren't we kind… */
    display: inline-block; /* …to IE6 :p */
}
#portfolio a {
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I apologize for not getting back sooner but this really solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#portfolio a.cboxElement{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border:3px solid #fff;
}
```

To answer the "Why?" part of your question, it looks like there's a bug in the browser that's triggered by opacity on some inline elements. Setting the display mode to block will work around it.

Also: which version of Opera are you using?

Comment: From what the person had told me, they were using the latest version of Opera.  But I haven't tried this yet and will let you know when I try this.

Comment: I saw it in Opera 11.01, which was the latest ("stable") at the time, but at this point could be several versions old.  Opera likes having multiple versions in the wild more than it likes not being buggy. :p

Comment: Got it. I've reported it as a bug. Thanks!  @reisio, 11.01 is still the latest stable release, though stable doesn't mean bug free :-).

Comment: Hi webinista, do you have the issue ID of the bug report? I looked into a very similar issue just this morning actually, I could probably give your report a small kick ;)

Comment: yep: DSK-327684 (It's internal)